# Storing function output in a list in R

Tags: r, list, function, seq

I have the following data frame

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(0,100,5), B = c(0,100,10), C = c(0,100,25)
```

which I use with this function

```
for(i in c(1:3))) 
{seq(df [1,i], df [2,i], df [3,i])
}
```

I need store the output but so far I only managed to print the results using

```
{y<-seq(df [1,i], df [2,i], df [3,i])
print(y)}
```

Instead I would like to store these output in a list to obtain something like

```
[[1]]
[1]   0   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60  65  70  75  80  85  90  95 100

[[2]]
[1]   0  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100

[[3]]
[1]   0  25  50  30  100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lapply` instead of `for` loop

```
> lapply(1:3, function(i) seq(df[1,i], df[2,i], df[3,i]))
[[1]]
 [1]   0   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60  65  70  75  80  85  90  95 100

[[2]]
 [1]   0  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100

[[3]]
[1]   0  25  50  75 100
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution here is to use lapply as @Jilber.

In case you want to know how to append a list:

```
result = list()             
for(i in c(1:3))
{
  result[[i]]<- seq(df [1,i], df [2,i], df [3,i])
}
result
```

Comment: I would suggest using `result <- vector("list", 3)` in order to avoid Circle 2 from [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

`lapply` is the way to go. Here is another approach that uses the fact that a `data.frame` is simply a list.

```
lapply(df, function(x) do.call(seq,as.list(x)))
# $A
# [1]   0   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60  65  70  75  80  85  90  95 100
#
# $B
# [1]   0  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100
# 
# $C
# [1]   0  25  50  75 100
```